# Dynamic tablename to %rowtype

Tags: database, oracle

In oracle is it possible to dynamically assign the table name with Rowtype anchor element.
If not is there any other way to achieve this scenario ?

Comment: Please elaborate what you are trying to accomplish.  But no, %rowtype is a compile-time directive

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what "scenario" it is, but - to me - looks like function that accepts table name as a parameter and returns ref cursor *might* be what you're looking for. Here's an example.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test (par_table_name in varchar2)
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    rc sys_refcursor;
  5  begin
  6    open rc for 'select * from ' || dbms_assert.sql_object_name(par_table_name);
  7    return rc;
  8  end;
  9  /

Function created.
```

Testing: pass `DEPT` table name, and you'll get its contents:

```
SQL> select f_test('dept') from dual;

F_TEST('DEPT')
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
```

Now pass `EMP` table name:

```
SQL> select f_test('emp') from dual;

F_TEST('EMP')
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17.12.80        800                    20
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20.02.81       1600        300         30
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22.02.81       1250        500         30
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02.04.81       2975                    20
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 28.09.81       1250       1400         30
      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 01.05.81       2850                    30
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09.06.81       2450                    10
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 09.12.82       3000                    20
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17.11.81       5000                    10
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 08.09.81       1500                    30
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 12.01.83       1100                    20
      7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 03.12.81        950                    30
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03.12.81       3000                    20
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23.01.82       1300                    10

14 rows selected.


SQL>
```

Comment: Here i am trying to archive set of tables from one schema to another schema through batch insert..So i am facing problem to assign the rowtype tablename dynamically.

Comment: Ah, it's *you*, again, with the same problem. My comment is the same as I posted for your previous question: don't reinvent the wheel, use Export (and then Import) **Data Pump** utilities.